# Cannot scroll on Ionic4 application with Hammer events

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4, hammer.js

I have a big problem with Ionic4 and HammerJS... for my `ion-list` I have many `ion-item` elements with `(tap)` and `press` events. Because scrolling not works if I´m using HammerJS, I have the following CSS property: `[style.touch-action]="'pan-y'"`

The complete code:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let book of bibleBooks | calculateProcess: selectedBookType; let i = index"
                      (tap)="selectBibleBook(book); selectedItem=i;scrollVersesToTop(); setCurrentBook(i)"
                      (press)="openBookFunctions(book, selectedBookType)"
                      [style.touch-action]="'pan-y'"
                      [class.active]="selectedItem == i"
                      [class.currentBook]="i == currentBook"
>
```

The problem:

This code works on my iPhone 8. I can scroll vertically. But on other iPhones, for example iPhone 5s or iPhone 7, scrolling is not working if I touch an `ion-item` element. Also on Simulator I cannot scroll...

What can be the problem? I´m using `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` version `^4.1.1`.

Comment: Have you imported `hammerjs` in `app.module.ts`?

Comment: Sure  otherwise gestures would not work..

Comment: have you found a solution? i am facing the same issue